# How can I add a new condition for 'confirmed' users signing in with passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to add a conditional to passport.js that also checks if the account is confirmed or not by inserting an 'if statement' to the bottom of the code after user email and password have been checked.

I tried several ways to add the if statement to the last part of the code in the 'LocalStrategy' function and tried reworking the whole thing with elif, and else statements. I'm getting 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' and other errors as it is below.

I'm afraid I can't provide all the code for you to reproduce this.
Unless you have a mock sign page and mongodb running with passport.js sign in and an account with a true/false like user.confirmed is for my account.

```
  const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

  // Load User model
  const User = require('../models/User');

  module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
        // Match user
        User.findOne({
          email: email
        }).then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
          }
          // Match password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.sendStatus(500);
              return;
          } if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
            }
          });
          // LINES I'M TRYING TO ADD HERE BELOW

            if (!user.confirmed) {
              return done(null, false, { message: 'This account is not confirmed' });
          // LINES I'M TRYING TO ADD HERE ABOVE
            }
        });
      })
    );

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });
  };
```

In my setup the above code is in the config file as passport.js and used by a js file in the 'routes' folder that logs the user in with

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
```

The field 'confirmed' is either 'true' or 'false'. Read with !user.confirmed. (The process of confirmed or !confirmed is handled with a link sent to the user's email. This is outside the scope of my issue but sharing in case this helps frame the problem.)

I would like for passport.js to check the account with the email exists, that the password is correct, THEN let the user login ONLY if the account is confirmed 'true' and post the message that the account is not confirmed and deny entry if it is not confirmed.

I can't seem to add the confirmed check without errors and losing the other checks for things. With this current setup it tells you if the email is NOT registered. It tells you if the user is NOT confirmed, but it crashes if you enter the wrong password with a registered email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So unless I am missing something

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
    return;
  }

  if (isMatch && user.confirmed) {
    return done(null, user);
  } else if (isMatch) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'This account is not confirmed' });
  } else {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
  }
});
```

Other permutations are available.

Comment: That covers every possible option without error. I actually tried 'else if' with 'elif' since I'm new to js from python and why it was rejecting was a blind spot for me. Chalked it up to a node/ passport.js issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask a slightly off topic question if I have you? Can a link be placed in the 'message'? I want unconfirmed users to be able to navigate to the 're-send activation link' page I have. Can that be in the message so I don't have to place it on the login page for those who won't need it?

Comment: @Renoldus absolutely, you can return HTML as a string, you must need to render it as pure HTML at the client.

Comment: { message: '<a href="www.google.com">click me</a>' }); tried this and a few variations. No luck yet. Just returns all the text as plain text. I'll have to dig around and figure out what I'm using. The message pops up from a bootsrap package so maybe it has to do with that.

Comment: @Renoldus I've no idea how you are rendering the client, however, simple example on the client would be `htmlElement.innerHTML = '<a href="www.google.com">click me</a>`

Comment: I'm always apprehensive about asking a stupid question on Stack Overflow since passing superusers seem to ban one for them... but I don't know which part is the client. It's from this project. https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login The guy has a tutorial. I find it difficult to wade into a new tech area and learn how to ask what I wanna know. (He doesn't put links in these messages in the tutorial.)

Comment: @Renoldus no worries, so looks like all the message rendering happens in [partials/messages.ejs](https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login/blob/master/views/partials/messages.ejs), and you can see each one is being HTML _encoded_ i.e. `<%= %>`, this means any HTML would be safely encoded (as to avoid XSS etc.). Given you have control over this message and is generated from the server, it's safe to render it unencoded via `<%- %>` - you only need to do this for any messages that you want to render HTML in.

Comment: Got it now. The workings of that partials/ messages page is now less mysterious, somewhat. Got it working now. Thank you.